linked table in MS ACCESS that is linked to EXCEL worksheet stops at 549 records
I need to do various calculations , analysis and reporting on data in EXCEL file, so i linked the Excel worksheet as a linked table in MS ACCESS. The tables worked great and data is updated seamlessly. However as file kept growing, the linked table showed records only up to 549 records, then it stopped and whatever rows above 549 added in Excel will not show in MS ACCESS linked table.
To reproduce the problem , 1st create a linked table in MS ACCESS :
1- Open MS ACCESS then > External Data tab > New Data Source > From File > Excel
2 - Select Excel File, and click the last radio option in the dialog box , (link to the data source by creating a linked table )
3 - Now the table will appear in MS ACCESS (with a green excel icon)
[Desired Behavior] :
The linked table in MS ACCESS is expected to show ALL records same as in the Excel file
[The Problem Occurring] :
The linked table in MS ACCESS shows only first 549 rows. When data is added to excel files , only up to row 549 appears in MS ACCESS. So MS ACESS does NOT show all data as expected.
How Can I make MS ACCESS shows all rows from Excel file using a linked table ?

I cannot replicate this issue. Suggest you post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide yours for analysis.

If you delete rows around 549 (say rows 545 to 554), does it still show the first 549? I suspect a control character in data preventing Access to read past it.
